# Fade in/out element on parent div hover with css

Tags: html, css

I want to show effect on hover, I've two Next/Prev button and I want to make then fade in/ fade out on parent div hovering.

My Html:

```
<div id="cslider">
   <a href="javascript:;" class="control_next"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
   <a href="javascript:;" class="control_prev"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i></a>
</div>
```

Comment: So what have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `transition` and `opacity` to make it work for you, as `opacity` is transitionable and also gives the same effect, without leaving the DOM:

```css
#cslider {
  padding: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

#cslider a {
  opacity: 0.25;
  transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}

#cslider:hover a {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="cslider">
  <a href="javascript:;" class="control_next"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
  <a href="javascript:;" class="control_prev"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Praveen but I need effect when #cslider on hover so not working

Comment: @GovindSamrow Just put the `:hover` for the `#cslider`. As simple as that.

Comment: Fade out /in not working properly, I think need to set "transition" on hover too.

Comment: @GovindSamrow Might work. Yea, okay. What else are you expecting from my answer? Do you have any more questions that I can help you with?

Answer (score 0):

On-hover `#cslider` it reduce the opacity of both `prev and next icon`.

```css
#cslider > a{
  opacity:1;
  transition: opacity 0.6s ease;
}
#cslider:hover > a{
  opacity:0.1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="cslider">
   <a href="javascript:;" class="control_next"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
   <a href="javascript:;" class="control_prev"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery (I'm assuming this is the case which is often true with sliders), you could use this piece of code to detect hover activity:

```
`$('#cslider').hover(
  function() {
    $('.control_prev,.control_next').fadeIn();
  },function() {
    $('.control_prev,.control_next').fadeOut();
  } 
);`
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/aWhoxIxAOIAUOy5lDwQF?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks, But only CSS Applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Working very smoothly for me:

```css
a {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: visibility 0s 2s, opacity 2s linear;
}

#cslider:hover  a {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 4s linear;
}
#cslider{
  padding:100px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="cslider">
  <a href="javascript:;" class="control_next"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
  <a href="javascript:;" class="control_prev"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with opacity and visibility, it's more easier to handle animations with this properties in CSS. You can add transform from X or Y, and even 3D. Here is the code:

```
#cslider .control_next, #cslider .control_prev {
   opacity: 0;
   visibility: hidden;
   transition: all .3s ease;
}

#cslider:hover .control_next, #cslider:hover .control_prev {
   opacity: 1;
   visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: **1.** Why are you using `visibility`? **2.** Why don't you explain something in your answer?

Comment: Because with opacity you can do animations , for example you can add transform here however you want. And your element must have visibility hidden because it will be clickable in another way.

Comment: `opacity: 0` is clickable as well. Giving `visibility` will screw up the transition. FYKI.

Comment: It would be better if you remove the `visibility` part, seriously.

Comment: Nop, i am using this every day and all is working properly

Comment: Just saying, having `visibility` or not, doesn't make a difference here. Do you agree?

Comment: No, try to read about visibility. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp ... However, the element will still take up the same space as before. The element will be hidden, but still affect the layout

Comment: Show me a difference between these two codes: http://output.jsbin.com/xocinuyaru, and if you could, I will give you `1.00 ₹` in exchange! `:)`